# reference layout block from content block in episerver 6 R2

Tags: episerver, episerver-6-r2

In the OnLoad of a Content Block, can I reference programatically (a method from) the Layout block where it's sitting in?
e.g. I've a text content block which I placed in a custom Layout block in Episerver Composer 6 R2, I need to call a method from the Layout block and place the method result in a variable in the content block. Particularly interested in the syntax. Many thanks

Comment: http://world.episerver.com/documentation/other-products/episerver-composer/ would be your documentation for the Composer add-on to Episerver 6.

Answer (score 0):

Composer blocks in Episerver 6 are in fact stored as pages in the page tree, albeit hidden from the UI. In other words, you can always traverse Composer content using **DataFactory**.